# React.js - Implementing sorting of components

Tags: javascript, scope, reactjs, this, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to learn React concepts, especially re: state and dynamic UIs, by coding a small sports roster-like UI. I've included the code below and the whole app + visual is at http://codepen.io/emkk/pen/dGYXJO. This app basically creates player cards from an array of player objects I've defined earlier.

I would like to implement sorting of the player cards upon button click. I've created a `<Sort/>` component that renders the said buttons. I'd attach event listeners but don't know how to have that reflected in my `<Roster/>` component. I have tried many different approaches with `this.state` but can't seem to be get this to work. So please any help with implementing sorting or general advice would be much apprieciated!

```
class ProfileCard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="profile-card">
        <figure>
          <img src={this.props.player.picURL} alt={this.props.player.Name}></img>
          <article>
            <ul>
              <li>{this.props.player.Name}</li>
              <li>{this.props.player.position}, #{this.props.player.number}</li>
              <li>{this.props.player.Club}</li>
              <li>{this.props.player.Height} ({this.props.player.Meters} m)</li>
              <li>{this.props.player.Age} years old</li>
            </ul>
          </article>
        </figure>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

class Roster extends React.Component {
  render() {

    // Store sorted version of data
    // Where I'd implement selected sorting
    var sorted = this.props.players.sort();

    /*
    * Create player cards from JSON collection
    */
    var cards = [];
    sorted.forEach(function(player) {
      if (player.year > 2000) {
        cards.push(<ProfileCard player={player} />);
      }
    });

    return (<div>{cards}</div>);
  }
}

class Sort extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sort-section">
        <h1>Sort by</h1>
        <div className="pill" id='age'>Age</div>
        <div className="pill" id='Meters'>Height</div>
        <div className="pill" id='Name'>Name</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class SortablePlayerTable extends React.Component {

  render() {
    /*
    * Prefix some interestings stats
    * before roster
    */
    var ages = [], heights = [];

    this.props.players.forEach(function(player) {
      if (player.year > 2000) {
        ages.push(player.Age);
        heights.push(player.Meters);
      }
    });
    var avgAge = (ages.reduce( (a, b) => a + b) / 12).toPrecision(3);
    var avgHeights = (heights.reduce( (a, b) => a + b) / 12).toPrecision(3);

    // Return page with stats data and Roster
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>2012 Olympic Men's Basketball Team</h1>
        <h2>Average Age: {avgAge} years old</h2>
        <h2>Average Height: 6 ft 7 in ({avgHeights} m)</h2>
        <Sort/>
        <Roster 
                players={this.props.players} 
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

React.render(
  <SortablePlayerTable players={PLAYERS} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**Solution:**

Another thing that tripped me up on the way to this was that I was losing access to `this.setState`, kept getting a `this.setState is a not a function` error. Using a ES6 arrow function to lexically bind `this` for my  handler function rescued me though.

```
class ProfileCard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="profile-card">
        <figure>
          <img src={this.props.player.picURL} alt={this.props.player.Name}></img>
          <article>
            <ul>
              <li>{this.props.player.Name}</li>
              <li>{this.props.player.position}, #{this.props.player.number}</li>
              <li>{this.props.player.Club}</li>
              <li>{this.props.player.Height} ({this.props.player.Meters} m)</li>
              <li>{this.props.player.Age} years old</li>
            </ul>
          </article>
        </figure>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

class Roster extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Create player cards from sorted, dynamic JSON collection
    var cards = [];
    this.props.players.forEach(function(player) {
      if (player.year > 2000) {
        cards.push(<ProfileCard player={player} />);
      }
    });

    return (<div>{cards}</div>);
  }
}

class Sort extends React.Component {
  sortRoster(field){
    var players = this.props.players;
    this.props.sortRosterStateBy(field, players);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sort-section">
        <h1>Sort by</h1>
        <div className="pill" onClick={this.sortRoster.bind(this,'Age')} >Age</div>
        <div className="pill" onClick={this.sortRoster.bind(this,'Meters')} >Height</div>
        <div className="pill" onClick={this.sortRoster.bind(this,'Name')} >Name</div>
        <div className="pill" onClick={this.sortRoster.bind(this,'position')} >Position</div>
        <div className="pill" onClick={this.sortRoster.bind(this,'number')} >Number</div>
        <div className="pill" onClick={this.sortRoster.bind(this,'Club')} >Club</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class SortablePlayerTable extends React.Component {
  state = {
   'players': this.props.players // default state
  }

  sortRosterStateBy = (field, players) => {
    // Sorting ...
    var sortedPlayers = players.sort( (a, b) => {
      if (a[field] > b[field]) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a[field] < b[field]) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });

    // Then call setState
    this.setState({'players': sortedPlayers});
  }

  render() {
    // Prefix some interestings stats before roster
    var ages = [], heights = [];
    this.props.players.forEach(function(player) {
      if (player.year > 2000) {
        ages.push(player.Age);
        heights.push(player.Meters);
      }
    });
    var avgAge = (ages.reduce( (a, b) => a + b) / 12).toPrecision(3);
    var avgHeight = (heights.reduce( (a, b) => a + b) / 12).toPrecision(3);

    // Return page with stats data and Roster
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>2012 Olympic Men's Basketball Team</h1>
        <h2>Average Age: {avgAge} years old</h2>
        <h2>Average Height: 6 ft 7 in ({avgHeight} m)</h2>
        <Sort players={this.props.players} sortRosterStateBy={this.sortRosterStateBy}/>
        <Roster players={this.state.players}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <SortablePlayerTable players={PLAYERS} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Attach a function to each `<div/>` in `<Sort/>` on clicking which it calls a parent function `this.props.sortBy()`

```
class Sort extends React.Component {
  sort(field){
    this.props.sortBy(field);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sort-section">
        <h1>Sort by</h1>
        <div className="pill" id='age' onClick=this.sort.bind(this,'age')>Age</div>
        <div className="pill" id='Meters' onClick=this.sort.bind(this,'height')>Height</div>
        <div className="pill" id='Name' onClick=this.sort.bind(this,'name')>Name</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Pass this parent function `sortBy` as `props` from your `<SortablePlayerTable/>` component.

```
class SortablePlayerTable extends React.Component {
  state = {
   players: [] // default state
  }
  sortBy(field){
    // Your sorting algorithm here
    // it should push the sorted value by field in array called sortedPlayers 
    // Then call setState
    this.setState({
      players: sortedPlayers
    });
  }
  render() {
    // calculate stats
    return (
      <div>
        {/* some JSX */}
        <Sort sortBy={sortBy}/>
        <Roster 
                players={this.state.players} 
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Now the sorted array will be available to your `<Roster/>` component as `this.props.players`. Render the array directly without applying any sort inside `<Roster/>` component.

Comment: Doesn't this require the anti-pattern of feeding props directly into state?