# filtering and sorting string array on match position in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a autosuggest control in Reactjs. I need to sort an array in which the matching items comes up and others will goes down.

For Ex. I have an Array : [ z , asxdf , abasdf , abcasdf , b , bc , cbd , c ] What I need is when I type a input KeyWord like "b" , then it should sort the given array in which all the string starting with b.. will come first and the rest after that. Which will generate final output : [ b , bc , cbd... (rest).]

So here I want perfect match at the top of the array and then other element will appear as per the index of match.

Comment: have you created a sorting function?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340987/react-js-implementing-sorting-of-components 

https://react.rocks/tag/Sort

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sorting