# How to shuffle an array of items in Gatsby without using props as initial state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby and so like most Gatsby apps, I'm fetching an array using `graphql`, then passing the `edges/nodes` (ie array of items) down via `props` to all the various `children/grandchildren/`etc.

However, I'd like users to be able to click on a shuffle button and shuffle this `array`. The answer given in [this SO answer seems to use props as initial state.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340987/react-js-implementing-sorting-of-components) I thought this was an [anti-pattern](https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/anti-patterns/01.props-in-initial-state.html).

But I don't see another way to do this...

So in my **index.js**

`let items = this.props.data.allItem.edges`

these `items` get passed down to a child component.

How can a button sort them and cue the re-render (via `setState`)?

Answer (score 0):

The link you sent about anti-pattern clearly reads that it's an anti-pattern to use props as state in the `constructor` or `getInitialState`. The correct way to do it would be using `getDerivedStateFromProps`:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

```
// this example sets this.state.items as a sorted version of the array that comes from props
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  return {
    items: props.data.allItems.edges.sort() // you can sort here
  };
}
```

This will ensure that your state will be in sync with the prop changes.

The next step would be to sort the items when clicking the button. The method that is run on button click would look something like this:

```
sortItems() {
  this.setState(state => ({
    items: state.items.sort()
  }));
}
```

When the state is changed, React automatically re-renders your component with the updated data.

Comment: but then how to do a re-render and new sort at the click of a button?

Comment: @KylePennell I just updated my answer. Basically, you just have to re-sort the state data every time you click the button and React will do the re-renders automatically.