# How to "sort by" using a button for the data i am displaying out here

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to add sort to the data by using a button

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";
import EmployeeCard from "./EmployeeCard";
import data from "./data.json";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import Subheader from "./Subheader";
import "./Employeelist.css";

function Employeelist() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ search: null });
  const searchSpace = event => {
    let keyword = event.target.value;
    setState({ search: keyword });
  };
  const employeeCards = data.employee
    .filter(data => {
      if (state.search == null) return data;
      else if (
        data.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(state.search.toLowerCase()) ||
        data.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(state.search.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        return data;
      }
    })
    .map(person => {
      return (
        <Col sm="4">
          <EmployeeCard key={person.id} person={person} />
        </Col>
      );
    });
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        class="elementStyle"
        onChange={e => searchSpace(e)}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>{employeeCards}</Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Employeelist;
```

Comment: I would suggest some "sortedArray" and "sortActive" component state, a button, a callback to toggle active sort, and the call to array::sort with whatever sort you need. The separate "sortedArray" is so you're able to maintain the original array if you toggle off any sorting.

Comment: Didn't get u @DrewReese

Comment: What have you tried so far? Start with adding a button. Then maybe attach a sort function to that button. Do you have any code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js - Implementing sorting of components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340987/react-js-implementing-sorting-of-components)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some state to hold the sorted/unsorted data and a sortActive boolean, and a handler to toggle the sort active or not. Use an effect to sort/unsort using the sortActive as a dependency.

Also fixed other discrepancies, I tried noting them.

```
function Employeelist() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ search: null });

  const searchSpace = event => {
    let keyword = event.target.value;
    setState({ search: keyword });
  };

  // state to hold sorted/unsorted data array, sortActive, and handler
  const [sortedData, setSortedData] = useState(data.employee);
  const [sortActive, setSortActive] = useState(false);
  const toggleSortActiveHandler = () => setSortActive(a => !a);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sortActive) {
      setSortedData(
        // Gotcha: array::sort is an in-place sort, meaning it mutates 
        // the existing array.
        // Spreading it into a new array then sorting addresses this.
        [...data.employee].sort((a, b) => {
          if (a.lastName < b.lastName) return -1;
          if (a.lastName > b.lastName) return 1;
          return 0;
        })
      );
    } else {
      setSortedData(data.employee);
    }
  }, [sortActive]);

  const employeeCards = sortedData
    .filter(data => {
      // filter returns true/false if element should be filtered
      if (state.search == null) return true;

      return (
        data.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(state.search.toLowerCase()) ||
        data.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(state.search.toLowerCase())
      );
    })
    .map(person => {
      return (
        <Col key={person.id} sm="4"> { /* <-- react key on outer most element */ }
          <EmployeeCard person={person} />
        </Col>
      );
    });

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        className="elementStyle"
        onChange={e => searchSpace(e)}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>{employeeCards}</Row>
      </Container>

      { /* button to toggle the sort */ }
      <button type="button" onClick={toggleSortActiveHandler}>
        Toggle Alpha Sort
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit simple data array sort toggle]

Comment: But if we have multiple sort option such as using firstname and age too we have to use "use effect()" three times with condition and even "const toggleSortActiveHandler" will be repeated three times for lastname and age, is there any other short option.

Comment: @MILANSAI Do you mean sorting by more than a single category, i.e. grouping (and sorting) on one category and then sorting within each group? Filtering on one attribute is trivial, more than one is not. You may want to look into rendering your data into module more suited to more complex sorting/grouping/etc... https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table comes to mind.

Comment: No suppose i need to sort according to firstname,lastname and age ,then according to this i need to create three useEffect()?

Comment: So, sort by firstName... or lastname ...or age? Just the ability to sort by any one of them at a time? If so, then I'd probably I'd probably create a map of sort type (first, last, age, none) to sort function, still keep a single "sortActive" but now it's a type instead of boolean, and simply look up in the map what sort function to use.

Comment: can it be done with only one toggleSortActiveHandler

Comment: @MILANSAI Absolutely it can. See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-data-array-multi-sort-toggle-zmqvf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark). It isn't much more code at all.

Comment: can we use dropdown like this.........   .....                                                                          <select  onChange="setSortTypeHandler(this)">
    <option value="SORT_TYPE.FIRST_NAME">First Name</option>
    <option value="SORT_TYPE.LAST_NAME">lastName</option>
    <option value="SORT_TYPE.AGE">Age</option>
    <option value="SORT_TYPE.NONE">None</option>
  </select>...........................But why its not working??

Comment: @MILANSAI Sure, updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-data-array-multi-sort-toggle-zmqvf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark). Issue is `onChange="setSortTypeHandler(this)"` isn't valid, should be `onChange={e => setSortType(e.target.value)}`, notice we can now directly set the state, no longer need the callback helper.

Comment: @MILANSAI This is a new issue, please open a new question and link it here and I can answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202946/not-able-to-display-modal-for-respective-viewmore-button