# Not able to display "Modal" for respective "viewmore" button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In app.js while displaying Modal clicking "view more" button for respective person, can see data in modal only for the last person.

link:-https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-tree-kjoim?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a single instance of the modal in the DOM (typically managed through a react portal), so when you map each person and create a modal, the last one set wins out. You can refactor the code to render just a single `Modal` and set the person you want displayed in it.

```
/**
 * Manage modal instance
 */
const [selectedPerson, setSelectedPerson] = useState({});
const openModal = person => {
  setSelectedPerson(person);
  toggleModal(true);
};
const closeModal = () => {
  setSelectedPerson({});
  toggleModal(false);
};
```

In the mapping on the button's onClick handler you want to call `openModal` to set the person and open state.

```
.map(person => {
  return (
    <Col sm="4">
      <EmployeeCard key={person.id} person={person} />
      <button onClick={() => openModal(person)}>VIEW MORE</button>
    </Col>
  );
});
```

Move the `Modal` to end of the render function and use the `selectedPerson` object and `closeModal` callback.

```
<Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} toggle={toggleModal}>
  <h1>
    NAME: {selectedPerson.firstName} {selectedPerson.lastName}
  </h1>
  <h3>AGE: {selectedPerson.age}</h3>
  <p>{selectedPerson.bio}</p>
  <button onClick={closeModal}>CLOSE</button>
</Modal>
```

[image: Edit open/close person modal]

[image]

Comment: I was trying to remove the button and clicking on the image should open the modal, but the image is displayed from Employeecard.js file,so is it possible to make the image as an onclick option,

Comment: @MILANSAI Yes, pass `openModal` as prop to `EmployeeCard`, attach `onClick={() => openModal(person)}` to `CardImg`. Sandbox updated.